# Python : Chaining commands

Tags: python, set

Concise code is prettier. So, I would go for

```
str_ = "Hello World    "
print str_.strip().replace(" ", "-").lower()
```

Compared to :

```
str_ = "Hello World    "
str_ = str_.strip()
str_ = str_.replace(" ", "-")
str_ = str_.lower()
print str_
```

However, in cases where the function returns incompatible objects (`None` for example), this won't work.

Case in point :

```
set1 = set([1, 2, 3])
set2 = set([1, 3, 5])
set3 = set()
set3.update(set1) #returns None
set3.update(set2)
set3.update(set1.union(set2))
print len(set3)
```

I was wondering if there is any way to chain commands like these too, maybe some parenthesis trick ?

Comment: *Concise code is prettier* Nope not at all. The clearer and less dense the code it is better. Do check out "obfuscated codes" which are very concise but completely unreadable.

Comment: So why are you updating `set3` with the union of `set1` and `set2` when it *already contains the union* through the `set.update()` calls?

Comment: I agree, some people stuff too much into a single line. But look at the example I chose. In cases like these, would you rather go for the latter ?

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary No, I would much rather have the explicit calls on multiple lines.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I really wasn't trying to accomplish anything of value with those commands but to show how tedious it can get.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary: but you missed that you produced the same union twice, and that you can chain `set.union()` calls, to boot.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed !
Also, I am now confused. Do you really think that in the example I chose to show chaining, the latter is recommended ?

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary: it depends on your use case as to what you should use. Avoiding creating completely new `set()` objects through chaining might not be ideal when you could update an existing `set()` object and avoid extra memory overhead, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sets have *in-place* methods, as well as methods that return a *new* object. `str` objects are immutable, so have no in-place methods, so only the methods that return new objects are left.

`set.update()` alters the set in-place, so you can't use that to chain, no. But if you use [`set.union()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) instead you get the *exact same result*, but as a *new* set:

```
set1 = set([1, 2, 3])
set2 = set([1, 3, 5])
print len(set1.union(set2))
```

`set.union()` can also be expressed using the `|` operator:

```
print len(set1 | set2)
```

You can chain these as much as you need:

```
print len(set1 | set2 | set3)
```

You may note that methods like `set.union()` are listed as available for both the `set()` and `frozenset()` types, the latter being an immutable type. Methods like `set.update()` however, are listed separately as only available for the mutable `set()` type.

Comment: do you mean " `set` objects are immutable..." ?

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary: no, `frozenset()` objects are immutable, `set()` objects are mutable.

Comment: Ok. So, there is no way to chain commands that alter the object *in-place* (eg `set.update()`, `list.sort()` etc) ?

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary: no, there are no methods on the object that mutate the object and return the object itself after mutation. You'd have to write separate functions for that.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you can frequently get what you want with operators such as `+` and `|`. If you prefer operator chaining but need to do operations in-place, you can write a wrapper class to do it.

```
class Chainer(object):

    """A proxy object that allows an object's methods be chained even
    if the methods themselves to not return a reference to the object.
    When object methods return a reference to self, several calls can
    be made on the object as in `someobj.method1().method2()` and etc...
    """

    def __init__(self, target):
        """Create a chaining proxy to target"""
        self.target = target

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'target':
            # let access to the proxied object through
            return self.__dict__['target']
        else:
            # get the proxied object attribute
            fctn = getattr(self.__dict__['target'], attr)
            if callable(fctn):
                # return a function that will call the proxied method, ignore
                # the return value and return a reference to the
                # proxy. The returned proxy can be used to call object
                # methods again.
                def caller(*args, **kw):
                    fctn(*args, **kw)
                    return self
                return caller
            else:
                return fctn


set1 = set([1, 2, 3])
set2 = set([1, 3, 5])
set3 = Chainer(set())
print len(set3.update(set1).update(set2).update(set1.union(set2)).target)
```

Comment: This is great ! Mind breaking down the code or pointing out some useful links ? +1

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary - added comments, hope it helps.